# Pass parameter to _beginthread function

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, beginthread

I have following code to start a new thread

```
int number = 10;
_beginthread(ModbusReadWrite, 0, (void*)number);
```

The function is:

```
void ModbusReadWrite(void *arg)
{
    char inBuffer[BUF_SIZE];
    int PointNumber = &arg;
    ...
}
```

It shows an error:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void **' to 'int'
```

So, I need to define new parameter of type int and pass it to ModbusReadWrite() function. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The void* parameter may be used to pass anything. But it makes no sense to take its address:

```
int PointNumber = (int)arg;
```